# How to stop jetty server on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, clojure, jetty

I used Clojure to start a jetty server on port 3000. Since then I have closed the command prompt.

Is there a way to view and stop the jetty server using Windows commands?

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 recommended ways.

1. If you [started Jetty with the `STOP.KEY` and `STOP.PORT` command line](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/start-jar.html#command-line-stop), then you can use those same values with the `--stop` command line option.
2. If you installed, configured, and then started [Jetty as a service](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup-windows-service.html), then you can use the windows service utilities to start/stop/restart Jetty.

Comment: I started jetty with this Clojure code: `(run-jetty handler {:port 3000})`. I did the getting started tutorial here: https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/wiki/Getting-Started.

Comment: Then your answer will be Clojure specific.